# Maxwell distribution of speeds

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

In a recently held physics paper we were asked to find the most probable speed for the molecules from an equation they gave. now, my question is this
In the maxwell distribution of speeds, isn't the number of molecules usually plotted on the y-axis?, if so, we should arrive at the conclusion that dn/dv should be zero for obtaining the most probable velocity but this is not the case according to the solution given

Comment: More details needed- what you get when differentiating looking for an extreme, and what solution they expect ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas ah yes the solution involves differentiating and getting the extreme from it

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas but what I'm asking is that in order to get the most probable speed should we assume dN/dv =0 (where n is the number of molecules and dv is a particular gap in the velocity distribution) or should we assume IT'S differential to be zero

Comment: Standard way of finding extreme of function $f(x)$ is solving differential equation $$ \frac {\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = 0 $$, unless there are some reasons to construct other ODE forms. This _may_ be the case here as wiki gives other ODE form satisfying Maxwell distribution : $$ kTvf'(v)+f(v)(mv^{2}-2kT)=0, $$, but I'm not sure about it.